# NestJS how to extend built-in services like ConfigService with a TypeScript interface?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

The NestJS [config docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-the-configservice) give an example of how to get type safety on `ConfigService` by using an interface like `EnvironmentVariables` and annotating it during injection like `constructor(private configService: ConfigService<EnvironmentVariables>) {...}`. However I would like to bind this interface permanently to `ConfigService` without needing to remember to import and annotate it at every injection point. I attempted this by re-exporting a TypeScript version using `extends` as shown below but this breaks the app, I think because extending a service means it's no longer the same service and so my extended version of `ConfigService` is no longer paired with the built in `ConfigModule`. What is the best way to fix this?

`config.service.ts`

```
import { ConfigService as NestConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

interface EnvironmentVariables {
  NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production';
  DATABASE_URL: string;
  JWT_SECRET: string;
}

export class ConfigService extends NestConfigService<EnvironmentVariables> {}
```

`users.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  providers: [UsersService],
  exports: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

`users.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '../config/config.service';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  async example() {
    return this.configService.get('JWT_SECRET');
  }
}
```

`error`

```
[Nest] 16612  - 05/17/2023, 2:15:03 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigService at index [0] is available in the UsersModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is UsersModule a valid NestJS module?
- If ConfigService is a provider, is it part of the current UsersModule?
- If ConfigService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UsersModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ConfigService */ ]
  })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigService at index [0] is available in the UsersModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is UsersModule a valid NestJS module?
- If ConfigService is a provider, is it part of the current UsersModule?
- If ConfigService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UsersModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ConfigService */ ]
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed extending the original Nest `ConfigService` doesn't override it from the Nest `ConfigModule`. Also, your custom service not being provided in any module but still being injected in your `UsersService` inevitably leads to an error.

You have to create your own `ConfigModule` that makes use of `NestConfigModule` and that both provides and exports your custom `ConfigService` :

```
import { ConfigModule as NestConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

@Module({
  exports: [ConfigService],
  imports: [NestConfigModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [ConfigService],
})
export class ConfigModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the code by @reginald but not working, I guess the reason is that `NestConfigModule.forRoot` used internal ConfigService insted of your extends class

https://github.com/nestjs/config/blob/fbac8a0617d27ab8284cab986eb8e2c9792ad257/lib/config.module.ts#L134

I tried to use custom provider and it works, I'm new to nestjs and it maybe is not best practices, you can try it.

```js
// configuration.ts
const getConfiguration = () => ({key:'value'})
```

```js
// config.service.ts
import { ConfigService as NestConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { getConfiguration } from './configuration';

export class ConfigService extends NestConfigService<ReturnType<typeof getConfiguration>> {}
```

```js
// config.module.ts
import { Module, Global } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';
import { getConfiguration } from './configuration';

@Global()
@Module({
  exports: [ConfigService],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ConfigService,
      useFactory() {
        return new ConfigService(getConfiguration());
      },
    },
  ],
})
export class ConfigModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

nestjs config module use its own ConfigService for its providers.
Their provider looks liek below. (not exactly same. simplified example)

```
const providers = [
{ provide: CONFIGURATION_SERVICE_TOKEN, useClass: ConfigService },
{
  provide: ConfigService,
    useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
      if (options.cache) {
        (configService as any).isCacheEnabled = true;
      }
      return configService;
    },
    inject: [CONFIGURATION_SERVICE_TOKEN],
  }
]
```

I think [codes from nestjst-typed-config](https://github.com/cashwalk/nestjs-typed-config/blob/main/src/typed-config.module.ts) can be a example in your case.
Custom config module which has forRoot static method. And its forRoot method requires config service as parameter. It supports dependency injection with input config service.

```
export class TypedConfigModule {
  static forRoot(
    configService: typeof BaseTypedConfigService<any>,
    options: ConfigModuleOptions,
  ) {
    const configModule = ConfigModule.forRoot(options);
    configModule.providers?.push({
      provide: TYPED_CONFIG_SERVICE_INJECT_TOKEN,
      useClass: configService,
    });
    configModule.providers?.push({
      provide: configService,
      useFactory: (typedConfigService: BaseTypedConfigService<any>) => {
        (typedConfigService as any).isCacheEnabled = !!options.cache;
        return typedConfigService;
      },
      inject: [TYPED_CONFIG_SERVICE_INJECT_TOKEN],
    });
    configModule.exports?.push(configService);
    return configModule;
  }
}
```

Additionally, if you want to use ConfigService, you can use [nestjs-typed-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-typed-config).

Answer (score 0):

As this post lacks complete accepted answer, and I had to assemble one from multiple up-voted comments, posting my complete solution for extending `ConfigService` as I wanted it to have method for forming plain object to provide to client instance:

`app.module.cs`

```
import { ConfigModule } from './config/config.module';
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [ MyClass ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`config/config.module`

```
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from "./config.service";
import { ConfigModule as NestConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config'; // <- mind the alias!

@Global()
@Module({
  exports: [ConfigService],
  imports: [NestConfigModule.forRoot({
    envFilePath: 'config.env', // <- just an .env file
  })],
  providers: [ConfigService],

})
export class ConfigModule {}
```

`config/config.service`

```
import { ConfigService as NestConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Logger } from "@nestjs/common";

interface MyEnvVars {
  USER: string;
  TOKEN: string;
}
export class ConfigService extends NestConfigService<MyEnvVars> {  // <-- brings
  private readonly logger = new Logger(ConfigService.name);

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.logger.log('Custom ConfigService initialized'); // <-- just for better visibility
  }

  public createCredentialsFromConfig = (): { user: string; token: string; } => {
    const user = this.getOrThrow<string>('USER', undefined);
    const token = this.get<string>('TOKEN', undefined);
    if (!(user && token)) {
      this.logger.error('check your config!');
    }
    this.logger.log('I got your token');  // <-- just for better visibility
    return { user, token };
  }
}
```

`my-class.ts`

```
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from "../config/config.service";

@Injectable()
export class MyClass {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(MyClass.name);

  constructor(
      private readonly configService: ConfigService, // <-- injected is custom ConfigService
  ) { }

  public doSomething() {
    console.log(this.configService.createCredentialsFromConfig());
  }
}
```

works on my machine (tm)